# Stuck At Initializing ADB - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

My Android Studio Logcat is stuck and does nothing. It displays `Initializing ADB` and does not show filtering options and does nothing

[image: screen shot]

Comment: tried to run `adb` from the command line? if so, what do you see?

Comment: But... The logcat has shown (some, at least)... So is the "Initializing ADB" failed to disappear?

Comment: no, i used an emulator from android studio interface

Comment: yes, but i cant interact with it or  change device @GenoChen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Invalidated Caches and Restart` did the trick. If is solved now. Thanks for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Few solutions i tried and which worked for me in different times :

1. Go in devices view, delete the device and create a new one.
2. Kill the adb through command line

   Before you execute the commands in CMD make sure that you added the adb tool to your Environment Variables path.

Killing adb

> adb kill-server

Starting adb

> adb start-server

other way of killing adb is Go to task manager->processes and kill the adb.exe process.

Even after doing all these if it prevails, the final thing i did is restarted my whole machine so that adb process is removed from RAM.

Hope it helped :)